# How to convert a Substrate address to an Etherum address?

Tags: account, ethereum

How can I convert a Substrate address to an Etherum address?

There is an EVM to substrate address conversion that Edgeware provides: https://edgewa.re/keygen

Comment: Please provide more context and explain the question in more detail: Which address formats? Do you want to do it in code or just in general?. Also, it's best not to repeat the title of the question in the question body.

Answer (score 10):

The Ethereum address correspond to the last 20 bytes of the keccak-256 hash of the (decompressed) secp256k1 public key.

For example, given the following key generated via `subkey` tool:

```
❯ subkey generate --scheme Ecdsa
Secret phrase `normal whale earth envelope wash bench drip latin please inform crisp congress` is account:
Secret seed:      0x6c51a7f71537a60e666288a292ceabf322202af75e39bc34fd10f576cee489a5
Public key (hex): 0x025f13d211338f64fcc941e80b9d71929c38a7147762541da4123de45cedb0b312
Account ID:       0x211e23eda1f535feb3abd690513a0c2731c4bb9940aad59f0fb3c8abe89308e1
SS58 Address:     5Cp8PdGYPGe2Vc5WLb4eUmbeuhxuDjPSQcpyWgVSjh97D9sR
```

Public key is given in compressed form:

```
Compressed:         0x025f13d211338f64fcc941e80b9d71929c38a7147762541da4123de45cedb0b312
```

Decompress it

```
Decompressed:       0x045f13d211338f64fcc941e80b9d71929c38a7147762541da4123de45cedb0b31290c16565dbc3c937fd1d9cf4ecc8ad489551a7d608ec5c649bec747183334754
```

Compute the Keccak-256 of the decompressed key (excluded the first byte (0x04))

```
Keccak-256:         0x09ed410a80b44d0a8c3e7e1fd924abdb51e253b19f69fd8114fe6d9a1794d2cf
```

The last 20 bytes is the Ethereum address

```
Eth Address:        0xd924abdb51e253b19f69fd8114fe6d9a1794d2cf
```

---

Said that, if instead you only have a Substrate AccountId (without the public key)  it is not possible to convert it to the corresponding ETH address.

The reason is that the AccountId is the result of a hash applied to the PublicKey (+ some other data) and thus it is not possible to revert it in order to recover the public key (and apply the procedure I've described above).

---

Here is a code snip doing the conversion in the Substrate Beefy pallet:

https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/87ebfdbcf8242c04856e3881a78ea0bc369d77a2/frame/beefy-mmr/src/lib.rs#L70-L89

Comment: What does it mean for a key to be compressed/decompressed?

Comment: A public key is a point in a curve. In order to recover the point is sufficient to have only one between x and y (typically x is chosen) and the sign of the other.

Comment: But what does it have to do with compression?

Comment: Since you are actually representing the same information with half of the data this is in fact a compression. It is called "point compression" in the SEC1 standard. Please refer to paragraph 2.3.3 of https://www.secg.org/sec1-v2.pdf